# When using ngFor on a div, how to autowrap items into two columns in angular2? Is there a way to do this with CSS only?

Tags: css, angular

I have a lot of "repeating div with display:block" that I want to be able to have 2 columns. Is there some way such that even though I am looping through items (could number anywhere between 10 - 100 to create these divs, that there is some css I could assign such that it will automatically wrap all the items in a two column layout where there is an equal distribution of "items" in each?

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <div *ngFor="let item of items" style="display:block;">
      <div> 
         <div class="chip blue darken-3">                        
            Item 1
         </div>
            Item 1 Value
      </div>
   </div>   
   <div style="display:block;">
      <div> 
         <div class="chip blue darken-3">                        
            Item 1
         </div>
            Item 1 Value
      </div>
   </div>   
   <div style="display:block;">
      <div> 
        <div class="chip blue darken-3">                        
           Item 1
        </div>
           Item 1 Value
      </div>
   </div>   
      ...

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of flex

```
<div class="parent" *ngFor="let item of items" style="display:block;">
    <div class="child"> 
         <div class="chip blue darken-3">                        
              Item 1
          </div>
              Item 1 Value
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: calc(100% * (1/2) - 10px - 1px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `ngFor` in a main div and add another class the for `ngFor` `div`.

css:

```
.two-a-row{ 
  float:left;
  display:table-column;
  width:50%;
}

.main-box{
  width: 50%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="main-box">
  <div class="two-a-row" *ngFor="let item of stations" style="display:block;">

     <div class="chip blue darken-3">                        
          Item {{item.item}}
      </div>
          Value {{item.item_detail}}
    </div>
</div>
```

[demo for 100 items](https://plnkr.co/edit/tZisyfGx8h5St173RJGi?p=preview)